# What's meanings of 【press on】&【tap into】right here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a short piece from one of my books called 365 Self-Displines.

> My goal to build a successful company was of immense importance to me,
>   but the path I chose was making me so miserable that I hated waking up
>   every morning. I could have ***pressed on***, tapping into the deepest
>   reservoirs of my willpower, but ultimately life was telling me that
>   this path wasn't for me.

So what's the meaning of "press on" in this context? I looked up dictionary, which says it means to continue with a task. Or is it like press a button on the reservoirs? I am not sure about it. I am torn between the two meanings.

Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I got the meaning of it. As you mentioned it means being reluctant to undertake the things the author doesn't like. I guess the author might refer to other books or other sources before his own thoughts come into being. Anyway, thanks for your answer. It really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Pressing on*** means to continue what you were doing in spite of the obstacles.  Usually, in this case, the obstacles have revealed themselves after the task has begun so one must re-evaluate one's commitment to the task. In other words, the task just got a lot harder. For this commitment, one must dig into one's (perhaps as yet unrecognized) personal resolve and strength (the **reservoirs**).